# Behaviour Subject is loading data in console but template is coming blank in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

I am working on an angular app where I am subscribing data in service and emitting data using Subject in `component.html` and in `component.ts` I am subscribing to get the latest value.

My problem is when I refresh the page I get data in the console but I don't see it on the template. Also, when I click on the router link again I can see the data after the first click.

**service.ts**

```
  public_Data= new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  getDemo2(){
    this.http.get<UPost[]>(`https://write-your-heart-out-b338b.firebaseio.com/post/${this.uid}/public.json`)
    .pipe(
      map(responseData => {
        const postsArray: UPost[] = [];
        for (const key in responseData) {
          if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key] });
          }
        }
        return postsArray;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(posts => {
      this.public_Data.next(posts)


      this.combine()
    });
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
 allpost: UPost[] = [];
  constructor(  private acrud: ACrudService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.acrud.getAllData()

    this.acrud.getDemo1();
    this.acrud.getDemo2()
    console.log("oninitnt methid")


   this.allSub= this.acrud.public_Data.subscribe(d=>{
      console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",d)
    })
```

**component.html**

```
 <div class="card row" *ngFor="let i of allpost  ; let c = index">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 main-content">
        <h2 class="title">{{ i.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ i.description }}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big issue here is that you're not handling the data reactively.  The simplest way to fix your issue is to change your component constructor to the following:

```
  constructor(  public acrud: ACrudService) { }
```

Then change your HTML to the following:

```
<div class="card row" *ngFor="let i of acrud.public_Data | async; let c = index">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 main-content">
        <h2 class="title">{{ i.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ i.description }}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working fine but how do i get individual post by id when i click on any post.because this approach is giving error

Comment: I run into state management questions quite often on StackOverflow.  I've created a sample StackBlitz that illustrates how to maintain state when using services.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ikemtz-playground

Have a look.  If you have any questions please let me know.